# How to Field Array with Map passing a Dynamic set of Fields

Tags: javascript, arrays

**ANSWER CODE BELOW:**

Poking around the internet I see functions that get me part of the way to what I need.  However, I am trying to make this more dynamic.

Original array:

```
[
  { Id: 1, Field1: 'Value10', Field2: 'Value20', LastSaveDate: 'xxx', LastSaveUserId: 2, Field3: 'Value30' },
  { Id: 2, Field1: 'Value11', Field2: 'Value21', LastSaveDate: 'xxx', LastSaveUserId: 2, Field3: 'Value31' },
  { Id: 3, Field1: 'Value12', Field2: 'Value22', LastSaveDate: 'xxx', LastSaveUserId: 2, Field3: 'Value32' }
]
```

So the following code will take a constant set of fields and remove them from the output array.

```
const dataSet = items.map(({ Id, LastSaveDate, LastSaveUserId, ...item }) => item);
```

Would return:

```
[
  { Field1: 'Value10', Field2: 'Value20', Field3: 'Value30' },
  { Field1: 'Value11', Field2: 'Value21', Field3: 'Value31' },
  { Field1: 'Value12', Field2: 'Value22', Field3: 'Value32' }
]
```

That is great, however, I want that `Id, LastSaveDate, LastSAveUserId` portion of the map to be passed in as an array or object or something dynamic so I can make a more useful function out of it like this:

```
exportToCSV(items, fileName, discardedFields) {
  ...
  const dataSet = items.map(({ discardFields, ...item }) => ({ item }));
  ...
}
```

**ANSWER**

Expanding on @Felix Kling below, here is what I now have that works.  I also added some fields that were constant across many if not all exportable datasets.

```
removeFieldsFromObject(obj, fields) {
    const commonRemovals = ['Id', 'LastSaveDate', 'MapData','LastSaveUserId'];
    const removals = new Set([...fields, ...commonRemovals]);

    return Object.fromEntries(
        Object.entries(obj).filter(([field]) => !removals.has(field)),
    );
},

exportToCSV(items, fileName, discardFields) {
    ...
    dataSet.forEach((item, index) => {
        dataSet[index] = this.removeFieldsFromObject(item, discardFields);
    });
    ... // dataSet now has only the desired fields to export
},
```

Calling this method would be something like this:

```
ExportToCSV(items, 'Sites', ['AnotherField', 'ThisField']);
```

So the final array would NEVER include the following fields: `Id, LastSaveDate, MapData, LastSaveUserId, AnotherField, ThisField`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create another helper function to select (or discard) the fields by simply iterating over the array and creating a new object:

```
function discard(obj, fields) {
  const result = {};
  fields = new Set(fields);
  for (const field of Object.keys(obj)) {
    if (!fields.has(field)) {
      result[field] = obj[field];
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Or more "functional":

```
function discard(obj, fields) {
  fields = new Set(fields);
  return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(obj).filter(([field]) => !fields.has(field))
  );
}
```

Comment: I expanded on it a bit, but you got me there @Felix Kling